# How to set Date time to 00 Javascript

Tags: javascript, date

I have a problem. I have date picker in my web and when I pick date time must be 00.
This is what I tried:

qs.date = 2020-11-04T22:00:00.000Z

```
qs.date = new Date($scope.input.date.getFullYear(),$scope.input.date.getMonth(),$scope.input.date.getDate()+1,0,0,0);
```

And it does not change the hours to 0 it always stays 22

Also I tried to use this:

```
qs.date.setHours(0,0,0);
qs.date = qs.date.toISOString();
```

But no luck.

[image: network header]

Comment: 1) post text, not images 2) don’t (confusingly) assign a different type to the same variable 3) probably has to do with TZ

Comment: The date you are looking at is UTC , setHours is locale time, setUTCHours is UTC .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using [`setHours`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setHours), where the time is expressed in the **local** timezone of the browser, but then you're using `toISOString`, which gives you a string expressed in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time). If you want the time to be `00:00:00` UTC, use [`setUTCHours`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setUTCHours): `.setUTCHours(0, 0, 0, 0)` (note that fourth `0` — milliseconds *[thanks RobG!]*).

Answer (score 0):

qs.date = new Date($scope.input.date);

qs.date.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30089336)